# I am unable to see recent calls,dailed calls after installing 5.1

Tags: history

I am unable to see recent calls,dailed calls after installing 5.1.
Any idea why it is.Which default apps are responsible for this? I stopped few default apps like google news,music etc.

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: Issue resolved after i took backup and reset to factory settings. Even i got my contacts back.Thank god.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after i took backup and reset to factory settings. Even i got my contacts back.Thank god.
And even the version remain same as 5.1 only but everything fine. But i didnt find how to set to vibrate or silent in this.